# Using 3D OBJ file in Blend 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, 3d, blend

I just started to lean WPF 3D and follow the tutorial. I created a 3D Model and exported it as OBJ file. Created a new WPF project and added this OBJ file. How I can use it inside `Window` or `Viewport3D` ? I found a link from Microsoft at: [Import 3D content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294912.aspx) but it written for Expression Studio and there's no 'Insert' option in Blend :( I could not drag it on `Window` because of 'disabled' icon when dragging

When I double click on OBJ file I can see my 3D Model in WPF window - so I guess that WPF could read this file.

P.S. Here is Blend showing my 3d Model:

[image]

Comment: Have you ever got this working? I'm in the same situation right now and I don't find much material online covering the import process. I'm missing the import button option too :/

Comment: It is a pity that they removed this feature! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294912(v=expression.40).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, Luckily I still have VS2010 and VS 2013 on my computer, and their Blend counterparts. My work around is to open my project in blend 2013 ,import my models , save then re-open in 2015, or start the project in one of the older Blend programs import the models then continue the program in 2015.