# Using 3D Wavefront OBJ / STL in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, blend, wavefront

I want to import `Wavefront OBJ` or `STL` files into my `C# WPF` application.

On older post are walkthrough which I cannot use anymore.

- [Using 3D OBJ file in Blend 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856485/using-3d-obj-file-in-blend-2015)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/06b6c4e4-def3-439d-9d0f-6f0fa5a14e8f/expression-blend-blend-for-visual-studio-obj-and-xaml?forum=wpf

Is it no longer possible to 'easy' import these files and use it in **VisualStudio / Blend 2017**?

---

I found a tutorial with `HelixToolkit.WPF` and successfully imported some files:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/882885/Display-D-Model-using-Window-Presentation-Foundat

But it does not seem to be the perfect way for me. What I want to do is to export parts of a machine from `SolidWorks`, place them into my app and create a 3d visualisation of my machine.

It should be possible to see my objects in `designTime`!

Answer (score 1):

I used Scichart WPF to import some Solidworks part into WPF, it's a little tricky to use, but you will get what you want, but scichart couldn't make an animation, and you can only have 30 days for trial.
Here is an example:

```xml
<s3D:SciChart3DSurface Name="sciChart3DSurface"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       WorldDimensions="250,1,250">
 
    <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.Resources>
        <!--  The 3D chess objects models which are used in this example were created by Fabio Valle, objects are used for  -->
        <!--  demonstrating purposes only to show possibility how to load and manipulate the 3D objects on 3D scene. Fabio's email: fabiovalle3d@gmail.com  -->
        <object:ObjectModelSource x:Key="PawnLowObj3DSource" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/Pawn_Low.obj"/>
        <object:ObjectModelSource x:Key="BishopLowObj3DSource" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/Bishop_Low.obj"/>
        <object:ObjectModelSource x:Key="KingLowObj3DSource" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/King_Low.obj"/>
        <object:ObjectModelSource x:Key="KnightLowObj3DSource" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/Knight_Low.obj"/>
        <object:ObjectModelSource x:Key="QueenLowObj3DSource" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/Queen_Low.obj"/>
        <object:ObjectModelSource x:Key="RookLowObj3DSource" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/Rook_Low.obj"/>
        <object:Rotation3D x:Key="ObjRotationState" Axis="YAxis" Angle="180" />
        <object:TextureSource x:Key="BlackTexture" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/BlackWoodTexture.jpg" />
        <object:TextureSource x:Key="WhiteTexture" Source="pack://application:,,,/SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies;component/Resources/Objects/WhiteWoodTexture.jpg" />
    </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.Resources>
   
    <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.SceneObjects>
        <!--  The 3D chess objects models which are used in this example were created by Fabio Valle, objects are used for  -->
        <!--  demonstrating purposes only to show possibility how to load and manipulate the 3D objects on 3D scene. Fabio's email: fabiovalle3d@gmail.com  -->
        ...
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource RookLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.0625, 0.6, 0.9375" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource KnightLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.0625, 0.6, 0.8125" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2" Rotation="{StaticResource ObjRotationState}"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource BishopLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.4375, 0.6, 0.3125" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2" Rotation="{StaticResource ObjRotationState}"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource KingLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.0625, 0.6, 0.5625" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource QueenLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.0625, 0.6, 0.4375" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2" Rotation="{StaticResource ObjRotationState}"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource BishopLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.0625, 0.6, 0.3125" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2" Rotation="{StaticResource ObjRotationState}"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D DrawBoundingBox="True" BoundingBoxStroke="White" TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource KnightLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.3125, 0.6, 0.3125" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2" Rotation="{StaticResource ObjRotationState}"/>
        <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource BlackTexture}" Source="{StaticResource RookLowObj3DSource}" Position="0.0625, 0.6, 0.0625" CoordinateMode="Relative" Scale="0.2, 0.2, 0.2"/>
        ...
    </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.SceneObjects>
</s3D:SciChart3DSurface>
```

Here is a demo pic:
[image: Screenshot of a chess board rendered within a WPF application, produced by the above code.]